# IoT Data Plane Client - AWS SDK for JavaScript v3 - Function UpdateThingShadowCommand is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot

I am trying to update a thing's shadow on AWS IoT Core by calling the function 'UpdateThingShadowCommand' from my vueJS web app.

I am following instructions from the documentation here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-iot-data-plane/classes/updatethingshadowcommand.html

However, when I execute the method 'UpdateThingShadowCommand', I keep running into the following error message:

> net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

And another log message:

> TypeError: Failed to fetch

My code is as follows:

```js
import { IoTDataPlaneClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-iot-data-plane";
import { UpdateThingShadowCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-iot-data-plane";

myMethod () {

      const configIotDataPlaneClient = { 
        apiVersion: 'XXXXXXXX', 
        region: 'XXXXXXX', 
        credentials: {
          accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 
          secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        } 

      //Initializing the client
      const clientShadow = new IoTDataPlaneClient(configIotDataPlaneClient);
      console.log(clientShadow)

     const inputShadow = {
        payload: new Uint8Array(
          Buffer.from(
            JSON.stringify({
                "state": {
                    "reported": {
                      "item1": "val1",
                      "item2": "val2"
                    }
                }
            }),
          ),
        ),
        //shadowName: "",
        thingName: "thing-name"
      }

      //Updating a thing's shadow
      try {
          const commandShadow = new UpdateThingShadowCommand(inputShadow);
          console.log(commandShadow)
          const responseShadow = await clientShadow.send(commandShadow);
          console.log("Update Shadow response", responseShadow)
      }
      catch (error) {
          console.log("Update Shadow error: ", error)
      }
      finally{
          console.log("Update Shadow: finally method")
      }
}
```

Can anyone suggest why I may be getting these errors? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hello, are you still having the same issue? If not, would be nice if you can share what solved your issue and what was the cause of the issue. I am getting the wrong error "403 Forbidden" but I managed to solve mine by looking at your code. I needed to pass Uint8Array object instead of the normal JSON